# How to enforce Decimal dtype in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, decimal, pydantic, pandera

How can I stricly enforce a dtype Decimal in a pandas DataFrame?

To clarify: I am *not* looking for weak workarounds, such as rounding every time I write to or read from a column (and hope that no other operations happend elsewhere that might lead to unwanted results).

I really want to be 100% sure that whatever is written in that column, no matter where it might have come from, will always have exactly 2 significant digits behind the decimal point, end of story. And if a user intends to write something that's not in agreement, the whole thing should blow up (either producing a TypeError or ValueError). --> To avoid theoretical dicussions and motivate the usage a bit: I am dealing with a trading system, that's why saving anything other than 2 decimal points in that frame would be a hard error, always.

I have tried to assign a dtype, but without success:

```
from decimal import Decimal
df[col].astype(Decimal)
```

Pydantic comes to mind: but if I bake the df into a class (say `class MyDfType`), then do I need to write my own setter/getter functions into `MyDfType` for the contained dataframe (`MyDFType().df`) ensure that all values to/from certain cols are manually enforced to be Decimal?

Comment: `Decimal` will not allow you to vectorize any operation, one option that you might not have considered it to use integers and values as cents. My 2 cents (pun intended :p)

Comment: You can't do it with Pandas alone. You can use Pydantic or Pandera to define a schema for the dataframe and validate against it

Comment: Hi Panas, how would you implement this with pydantic? Write setters/getters and pass every operation on `df` through those? Or any built-ins I can use?

Comment: @mozway in ETL scenarios vectorization performance isn't important. Unexpected rounding or values that can't be stored in a database table because they violate constraints are far more annoying

Comment: @KingOtto I've used [Pandera's](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dataframe_schemas.html) Checks and schemas  for this which allows specifying a schema and validating an entire dataframe against it. `Decimal` is one of the available types. A nice trick is you can have Pandera infer the schema of a dataframe and save it to a Python file for editing

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Wow, this is perfect. I had no clue.. thank you so much! The `df` is already sitting in a `Transaction` class, so putting the schema there is great - and soo much easier than pydantic or manual setting/getting!